# Android Emulator not running on AMD processor

Tags: android, android-emulator, amd-processor

After October 2018 I know the Android Emulator was able to be run on AMD but required a few steps to be taken. I followed all of them:

- I have an AMD Ryzen 5 processor
- I'm using Android Studio 3.3
- I have Android Emulator 28.0.23
- I'm using an x86 Android Virtual Device
- 'Windows Hypervisor Platform' is enabled
- SVM was enabled in the BIOS

After all of this it was working on my pc for about 2 months. Then one day I tried to run an AVD and the error below appeared.

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
```

Does anyone have any thoughts as to why all of a sudden it stopped working?

Comment: See this bug report [Running Android studio emulators with AMD64](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123249411) You may wish to add any detailed logs of your experience to the thread.

Comment: It was not working too in my HP laptop (14-g102AU), with changed RAM to 8 GB and changed HDD to SDD 512 GB. When I clicked the triangle button of the emulator something popped up "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_4_API_33 has terminated." I had changed the virtualization in BIOS both enable and disable. Both not working. Anyone knows what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I've been getting the same problem as you with Ryzen 3 2200g

What I did was:

1. **From Tools- SDK Manager - SDK Tools**
   [Disable Intelx86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c53IF.png)

Then, when I tried to run AVD, for the first time I got a pop up saying that x86 images are recommended.

[Pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDdhW.png)

I created a x86 system image (Nougat API 25) and finally it was working.

Also previously I did the same as you:

1. Enable Windows Hypervisor Platform (then reboot)
2. Enable CPU Virtualization from BIOS

I hope this solutions fits you. Happy coding :)